# Optimisiing SQLite DB file for android

Tags: android, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am converting xlxs to CSV table and then finally convert them to Sqlite DB file using DB Browser for SQLite.

My Sqlite DB file size is around 25 MB,with 92k records

On processing conversion to db file ,i remove empty/white spaces between columns also,But it does not reduce file size,

Is there any ways of optimising/reducing file size to less than 20 MB using DB Browser for SQlite.

Will AutoVaccum mode can be used and  setting them to full/incremental will it work?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to prebuild the DB file for APK delivery. Are there a lot of strings in the data? [SQLite doesn't compress data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10824347/295004) So changing the string format may help. Alternative just put the compressed CSV in the APK and populate the database on initial install or some mix of having a pre-populated DB for common items for quick startup while inserting bulk CSV in background.

Comment: What is your table definition and some typical rows stored in it?

Comment: I am having table with around 15 columns and 93k rows of values for it.All column values are specified as text.

Comment: After creating ,Before creating table,if change autovaccum mode to incremental and then create the table and import the csv file to table,write the changes the db file and close them gives me around 16.2 MB of file from 25.2 MB,I am not sure of it impact,I want to know will there any impact for it,Can anyone let about it